# Call JS function once a dynamic table has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic

I've got a dynamic table which is loading on document.ready, it gets it's data using $.get from a PHP file, which gets the data from an SQL database.

I want to run tablesorter once the entire page has loaded, I've tried a few things suggested on the internet, including $.when(call $.get function), but none of them have worked.

Is there any way I could call the function after the table has fully loaded?

Comment: Yes.  There is a way.  If you'd like a more detailed answer, we need more details, specifically your code: your $.get code, a sample of your markup, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am not understanding the question correctly, but shouldn't you just use the success callback of the $.get() function to process the data you retrieved from your PHP?

There is also the .done() promise to check out as well.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the .done() function and it worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark the question as answered since it worked!